# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^1 \frac{ \sqrt{n^3}x\sin(nx)}{1+n^2x^2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

As the title says, I am trying to evaluate the limit of the integral 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{0}^1 \frac{ \sqrt{n^3}x\sin(nx)}{1+n^2x^2} \rm dx$$ It is easy to see that the sequence of functions $\displaystyle f_n (x) = \frac{ \sqrt{n^3}x\sin(nx)}{1+n^2x^2}$ converge to $0$ point-wise. I'm having trouble finding an integrable dominant for this sequence, or proving that this sequence is monotone which would be sufficient. Is this reasoning correct? And if it is, any help on finding the integrable dominant would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps more interestingly, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{0}^1 \frac{n^2x\sin(nx)}{1+n^2x^2} {\rm d} x=\frac\pi{2e}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that by letting $t=nx$, 
\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^1 \frac{ \sqrt{n^3}x\sin(nx)}{1+n^2x^2} dx&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{0}^n \frac{ t\sin(t)}{1+t^2} dt\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{ n\sin(n)}{1+n^2} }{(\sqrt{n})'}=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2\sqrt{n}\cdot n\sin(n)}{1+n^2}=0
\end{align}
where we used the L'Hôpital's rule.

P.S. The sequence $f_n(x)=\dfrac{ \sqrt{n^3}x\sin(nx)}{1+n^2x^2} $ is not uniformly bounded in $[0,1]$: as $n\to+\infty$,
$$f_n(1/n)=\frac{n^{3/2}1/n\sin(1)}{1+n^2(1/n)^2}\to +\infty$$

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same thing before, and reached the conclusion that the limit will be 0. Now I\m trying to prove it using dominant convergence, or monotone convergence if possible.

Comment: @MKBG See my P.S.